# How to improve Core Data performance?

Tags: iphone, core-data, performance, nspredicate

My app has a UISearchBar allowing user to enter search keywords. Each keystroke executes a Core Data query in order to display the results as text in search bar changes.

The problem is that search bar keystrokes are lagging pretty bad... surely because of slow fetching. Any ideas how to improve the performance?

My Core Data is backed with sqlite data store which contains 1000 objects.

```
// searchKeyword is the string appears in UISearchBar
// Both title and author may contain several words so I can't use BEGINSWITH
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(author CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (title CONTAINS[c] %@)", searchKeyword, searchKeyword];

NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setFetchLimit:10];

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

execute request and fetch the results
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                cacheName:nil];
NSError* error = nil;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[request release];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using CONTAINS slows it down. What you need to do is create a new table called searchWords (or whatever), and in that store all the words within your titles, made lower case and with accents removed. These have a relationship linking them back to the original objects. Make sure the word field is indexed.

Perform your query on this table, but instead of using CONTAINS or BEGINSWITH, do something like

word > "term" AND word < "tern"

Note that the first string in there is the search term, and the second is the search term with the last character incremented. This allows Core Data to use the SQL index to perform the search.

Apple have a [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345613?i=2041584141) WWDC session that explains this, including sample code. The sample code contains a class that handles normalising the string (I.e. Removing case), and incrementing the last character of a word in a unicode aware way.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thanks!!
I will look for that session and post it here if I'll find it.

Comment: Direct link: http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345613?i=2041584141
Hmm.. I waited a long time for your post. In the meantime I found it my self, struggling the internet :D It's on "WWDC 2010, Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS" at 35:06

Comment: Sorry I could not find the related sample code (and I am a registered dev). Could you provide a short code snipped? (normalization and char increment)

Comment: How would this work when I have pulled out all the words into a separate entity?  I'm currently using the predicate 'ANY words.word BEGINSWITH %@' but it's still much slower than I'd like.

Comment: After searching for some time, I've finally found the referenced [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/index.php?id=118) **and [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DerivedProperty/Listings/DerivedProperty_APLNormalizedStringTransformer_m.html)** (see method `normalizeString:` and especially `upperBoundSearchString:`). :-)

Comment: Helped me a lot to search through a database with millions of rows. Code how to increment the last letter of a String would be helpful and i think the query should be word >= "term" AND word <= "tern".

Answer (score 13):

While Amoyra's recommendation is sound, you also have a design issue.

Only the first letter typed into the search field should **ever** hit the disk.  After the first letter you should only be refining the search results of what is already in memory.

You should filter the array that is in memory (from the first letter search) using the predicate you already have and avoid executing a fetch request as it is unnecessary.

In addition, if you are going to search on data that is already in memory (such as living in a `NSFetchedResultsController`) then your entire search should only hit the objects in memory. Going out to disk is unnecessary and terribly wasteful.

Comment: Hi Marcus, this is really interesting point. But I think there is an issue with that solution. Clicking 'a' or 'e' as the first letter, will probably bring most of the objects from database (if not all). When dealing with large DB this single fetch can take very long time not talking about memory implications...

Comment: That situation would not change no matter what implementation you use.  Core Data will pull in skeletons so the memory usage would be as low as possible.  As you filter that memory usage would go down.  The solution definitely works as I have used it many times.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Good point, Marcus, but how do you do this with a NSFetchedResultsController? The `fetchedObjects` property is readonly...

Comment: When each char is pressed you filter the `-fetchedObjects` from the `NSFetchedResultsController` and then your table view reads off the array that results.  You never need to go to disk because you already have all of the possible results in the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  I would not use a second `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 4):

While it won't speed up the query, putting the lookup into a background thread will stop the keystrokes from lagging.

Comment: +1 But remember to execute only one background query at a time, and to get the latest search string on each query (or otherwise coalesce text field updates), and lower the thread/NSOperation priority until the UI performs decently.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am really trying to avoid multithread solution but I will do it if I'll have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) incrementally in order to have an index for past queries (result sets are pointed by the leaf nodes). but it won't increase the performance of a single query. You can also tweak the keystroke system, don't do a fetch after each single keystroke but only after a keystroke after which a time interval (as a threshold) passed before another keystroke is recognized

Answer (score -1):

When starting the app, build up a full trie, and adapt it when editing. Do not use that stupid predicate. You're only fetching a 1000 records, so that should take no time.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how can I build a full trie on app startup. Can I really build such title\author trie in advance?

Comment: Just build it in 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: better not to build it entirely but incrementally as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: SQLite might be slow, but it isn't so slow that you cannot read 1000 records of two fields when starting, isn't it? Otherwise I would seriously recommend using a real datastore.

Comment: Building incrementally when querying is no usable solution for an iPhone app. You *need* fast results the first time.