# How to Filter NSArray of around 200,000 NSDictionaries efficiently?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray

I'm working on an sample app in which, when every time user enter any character in search bar I have to filter `NSArray` of 200,000 `NSDictionary` elements according to entered characters. `NSDictionary` contains only two keys i.e. "`English`" & "`Meaning`";

up to now I'm doing this as below in `UISearchBar` `delegate` method

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",@"English",searchText];

    _searchResult = [_dictionaryData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
}
```

I feel this is not a proper way to do this and filtering taking time also.

**P.S. - NSArray I'm filling up using core data**

Comment: Just if somebody doesn't know it: 1 lakh = 100000.

Comment: If the data comes from a Core Data fetch request then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21002171/1187415.

Comment: use TRIE type of data structure.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @MartinR what that answer suggested (in your shared link) I'm already doing. When app launches I load data in an array and use that array as datasource I'm not hitting disk every time.

Comment: I'd be very curious to know the performance of this. Search 200K records, on a mobile device, any time you enter a char.... So, if for "e" you have 199K hits, you return them all ? or "The", 45K hits ? What on earth whoever wrote the software specs was thinking about?

Comment: @Alex I really didn't understand, what you trying to pointing out?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma first off, if you really need to search, and use core data, perform the search IN the core data records. Not on the NSDictionnary. Memory wise, that's going to save you a lot of problems. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html . It's just my two cents, but performing a wild search on 200k words isn't efficient. You should limit the first search to the most common English nouns (2K only), then extend if it doesn't return any hits. Also, the [contains] predicate is very expensive to run. ..

Comment: so, you should restrict to BEGINWITH first, and may use CONTAINS as as last resort. The whole point is: If a search returns 1000 results, what is it good for ? What a human can do with 1K responses to a single question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you emphasize on *efficiency* you should transliterate your given words into some "normalized" form which consists only of ASCII characters. Keep these words in an dedicated `NSArray` or some other sort of container (e.g. `std::vector`).

The search string must be transliterated in the same manner. Then, the search function will be efficient, since it only has to find the given search string as a substring in the given word.

You can implement the search algorithm without using predicates. Preferable, you shoudln't use `NSArray` and `NSString`, but instead use a `std::vector<std::string>`, that is use C++.

You obtain the meaning for a found (normalized) word by lookup in an additional `NSDictionary`.

For transforming the string into a transliterate form, you may take a look at the following references:

- [[NSString] dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-dataUsingEncoding_)
  with encoding equals `NSASCIIStingEncoding` and allowLossyConversion set to `YES`.
- [[NSString] stringByFoldingWithOptions:locale:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW31)  using option NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch and (likely) the current locale.
- [CFStringTransform()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better idea will be to put all this into SQLLite database and filter it using SQLLite mechanism.

I don't think that with NSArray you can be faster than predicate is.

Also it will improve a lot memory usage by your app - it doesn't make sense at all to put all those entries into memory at one time. It's better to keep only the one that are visible on screen - if you use CoreData for that there is an easy way to that - check [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you want some good tutorial for Core Data go for:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: I have to use core data.
Is filtering object in NSArray using predicate costly operation than querying data base?

Comment: Database will be waaay faster with that + it will not consume so much memory during that process. If you keep everything in an NSArray you are probably using a lot's of memory for nothing, because you don't need all data constantly in memory.

Comment: ok!!! I'm new to core data, can you suggest some way to query efficiently to data base using core data.

Comment: ok, I have tried some way I'm getting "unimplemented SQL generation for predicate", how I'm forming predicate I'm posting in next comment please look into it and point out what I'm missing

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_NAME inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",@"Tamil",searchText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:searchPredicate];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    
    _dictionaryData = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

Comment: I added a good tutorial in my answer. It's too much to write in comments ;) If you have any specific question to core data better create new question later.